# How to Select a Specific (Variable) Column from an Array Apps Script

Tags: javascript

Surprisingly, I have not found an answer to select column `n` from an array, where `n` is a variable. I found a great code where I can put in a fixed value for `n` as in the following example:

```
var data = [[3.0, 11.0, 101.0, "Submarine"], [4.0, 11.0, 102.0, "Boats"], [5.0, 11.0, 103.0, "duh"], [6.0, 11.0, 104.0, "cars"]]; //example array called data

var newArray = data.map(function(column){ 
return column[3];});
```

Then `Logger.log(newArray)` returns the 3rd column as desired, [Submarine, Boats, duh, cars].

My question is how to turn this into a **function** of the variable column `n`? I've tried:

```
function newArrayFunction(n){  data.map(function(column){ 
return column[n];});
```

But sadly, newArrayFunction(3) for example returns "null".

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return anything, hence null.
try

```
  function newArrayFunction(n){ return data.map(function(column){
return column[n]})}
```

Comment: @KimHopkins if that solved your case, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the other answers return the column as a **row**. To return the column as a column, I modified @Nizar Zizoune's code as follows:

```
function newArrayFunction(data,n){ 
  return data.map(function(column){
  return [column[n]]
  })
  }
```

Simply adding the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [[3.0, 11.0, 101.0, "Submarine"], [4.0, 11.0, 102.0, "Boats"], [5.0, 11.0, 103.0, "duh"], [6.0, 11.0, 104.0, "cars"]];

function newArrayFunction(n=3) {
  const oA = data.map(function (r) {return r[n];});
  Logger.log(oA);
  return oA;
}

Execution log
9:18:34 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:18:34 AM  Info    [Submarine, Boats, duh, cars]
9:18:35 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```